# Xamp - mysql (3306 error)

Tags: php, mysql

```
Problem detected!
14:26:36  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server   5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" xxx (PROJECT NAME)"!
14:26:36  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
```

I can't shake this error. Xamp Apache runs great, but can't figure out how to get mysql running.

I tried:

Change php.ini:

```
mysql.default_port=3307
mysqli.default_port=3307
```

and my.ini:

```
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
 port            = 3307
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
port= 3307
```

I don't want to uninstall Mysql workbench (as it has important dbs)
Additional information (I've Installed mysql workbench - not sure if this helps or not)

Answer (score 0):

You could use netstat -lp | grep 3306 to find out what program is already listening on port 3306 (you should see PID/Program name in last column) and stop that (maybe mysql is already running?).

Alternatively you could start the newly installed server on a different port. (edit my.cnf and change the default port there)

Comment: 3306 is being used by mysqld.exe. I'm trying to switch from workbench to HeidiSQL. I tried to make new session, but it says (Access denied by root@local, password:no). Read in forums, that I've to have Xamp->mysql turned on. Well, I got stuck here.